# Core-Plot, is there an automatic way to manage the amount of numbers on the axis?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

As seen on the picture below the x-axis is very crowded in this example. I do know that the scale can be changed in Core-Plotr via:

```
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0f);
```

...so it will make it easier to read.

My question is if there is a way to automate the scaling of the axis so when it get too crowdy the axis label change to continue to be readable?

I guess that one way is to check the number of data points and change via code but it would be convenient if it is available via Core-Plot.

Here is a picture that shows my test graph:

[image]

When is get at this stage i would like to change it so it shows every 5th number and then every 10th etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` labeling policy. There's a demo in the Plot Gallery example app that shows all of the available labeling policies.